# Take away brackets and spaces in json string

Tags: json, whitespace, brackets

The device_token contains brackets and spaces and I would like to get rid of it in the payload

This is a JSON payload going to the vendors API

```
{
    "audience": {
        "device_token": "< XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX >"
    },
    "device_types": [
            "ios"
    ],
    "notification": {
        "ios": {
            "alert": {
                "title": "INSERT_TITLE_TEXT_HERE",
                "body": "INSERT_BODY_TEXT_HERE"
            }
        }
     }
}
```

I would like the JSON to have the device_token:

```
{
    "audience": {
        "device_token": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    },
    "device_types": [
            "ios"
    ],
    "notification": {
        "ios": {
            "alert": {
                "title": "INSERT_TITLE_TEXT_HERE",
                "body": "INSERT_BODY_TEXT_HERE"
            }
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming processing language is javascript:

```
json.audience.device_token = json.audience.device_token.replace(/[<> ]/g, '')
```

For more information, please read `String.prototype.replace` docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you'd change the JSON object into a string, then just replace the text you'd like to.

Something like:

```
// Define the payload object
var jsonPayload = {
    "audience": {
        "device_token": "< XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX >"
    },
    "device_types": [
            "ios"
    ],
    "notification": {
        "ios": {
            "alert": {
                "title": "INSERT_TITLE_TEXT_HERE",
                "body": "INSERT_BODY_TEXT_HERE"
            }
        }
     }
};
// Turn the object into a String
var string = JSON.stringify(jsonPayload);
// Replace the arrows and spaces with empty strings
var updatedString = string.replace(/< /g,'').replace(/ >/g,'').replace(/\s/g,'');
// Replace the jsonPayload with your new version by parsing the string 
// where replacements have been made back into a JSON object;
jsonPayload = JSON.parse(updatedString);
```

That should work!

Comment: Thank you! It's a web interface I have and I only seem to have JSON file possibilities and no javascript. Any chance there is another way?